# How can I see all the views under a schema in Teradata?

Tags: teradata, teradatasql

Could you please help me figure out how I can find out what are all the views under a certain schema?

At the moment I know only the names of 3 of them but there are more.

What I know:

- [view1].[view_known_name_1]
- [view1].[view_known_name_2]
- [view1].[view_known_name_3]

What I would like to is **view_known_name_4**
from **[view1].[view_known_name_4]**

So what I would need is to list all views under [view1].

Thank you.

Comment: Metadata about all objects in all databases/users (=schema) can be found in `dbc`, e.g. to get all views in a database:`select * from dbc.TablesV where DatabaseName = 'view1' and TableKind = 'V';`

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.